# Nginx настроить кэширование в браузере

Tags: nginx, кэширование

Никак не могу настроить кэширование

```
location / {
    location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
        try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
    }
    location / {
        try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
    }
}
```

Пользуюсь: https://pagespeed.web.dev/

Не удается настроить кэш для элементов css|js. В чем тут может быть дело?

Ранее пылся настроить в .htaccess, через mod_headers. Что тоже не дало результатов, что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте заголовок ответа [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) в этом location:

```
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age: 86400"
    }
```

Проверьте наличие в ответе заголовков, которые могут изменять кеширование: `Expires, Last-Modified, Vary, Pragma, ETag`.